# how to count 4us with the clock of 8MHz in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I need to check the bus activity till 4us. So I need to count it. And clock is 8MHz. Please help me in this.

Will the following code work?

```
process(sync_dw_reg,data_edge) 
begin 
 if(rst_n='1' or data_edge='1' )then 
    gapen<='0'; 
 elsif(falling_edge(sync_dw_reg))then 
    gapen<='1'; 
 end if; 
 end process; 

 process(dec_clk,sync_dw_reg,rst_n,gapen) 
 begin 
 if(rst_n='1')then 
    gapcnt<="000000"; 
 elsif(gapen='1')then 
  if(dec_clk'event and dec_clk='1')then
     if(gapcnt="111111")then 
        gaperr_bit<='1'; 
     elsif(data_edge='1')then --if this condition comes within 4us then no setting of error 
        gaperr_bit<='0'; 
        gapcnt<="000000"; 
     else gapcnt<=gapcnt+'1';
     end if; 
  end if; 
 end if;
```

end process;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, figure out how many clock cycles 4us is at your clock rate.

Even better, get VHDL to do the work for you.  If you have a global package for your design with a constant in it which is the clock period:

```
constant clock_period : time := 125 ns;
```

you can then do:

```
constant bus_timeout_for_example : natural := 4 us / clock_period;
```

Then, create an integer variable in your process.  Increment it every clock cycle.  When it reaches the figure you calculated above, that's the end of your 4 us.

EDIT:
Now you've posted some code some comments:

- Don't use std_logic_vectors for arithmetic - http://parallelpoints.com/node/3
- Make the whole thing synchronous to one clk signal (ie dec_clk is all you have in the sensitivity list) - if you need to detect "edges" on other signals, store them and comapre them the next clock cycle to see if they've changed.  Having *_edge called on more than one signal in your whole design is asking for trouble (as a novice).  Then `gapen` can be a variable within the one process.  And check `gapen` inside the "clocked" part.
- Use a variable calculated as I describe and of an integer type - then you can compare with numbers : `if gapcnt = bus_timeout then`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its a nice way I think. And in mean time I tried something for the same in normal way. Could you please go through it and let me know if it works? Logic is, within 4us if there is any bus activity then there is no error or else if it exceeds 4us then an error.

Comment: process(sync_dw_reg,data_edge)
    begin
 if(rst_n='1' or data_edge='1' )then
  gapen<='0';
 elsif(falling_edge(sync_dw_reg))then
  gapen<='1';
 end if;
end process;

process(dec_clk,sync_dw_reg,rst_n,gapen)
begin
 if(rst_n='1')then
  gapcnt<="000000";
 elsif(gapen='1')then
  if(dec_clk'event and dec_clk='1')then
   if(gapcnt="111111")then
    gaperr_bit<='1';
   elsif(data_edge='1')then  --if this condition comes within 4us then no setting of error
    gaperr_bit<='0';
    gapcnt<="000000";
   else
    gapcnt<=gapcnt+'1';
   end if;
  end if;
 end if;
end process;

Comment: Sorry, the code is not in proper format as I have put in comment box.

Comment: I'm just curious what tool you're using for synthesis?  When I use time in Xilinx ISE I get an error that says "VHDL source expression not yet supported: 'PhysicalLiteral'."

Comment: I use Synplify.  Xilinx have 2 VHDL parsers - by default the new one is only used with S6/V6 upwards.  The new one may support this usage, but I'm not sure..